# Sequence with Streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

Suppose there is a sequence `a[i] = f(a[i-1], a[i-2], ... a[i-k])`. How would you code it using `streams` in Scala?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the rules of the sequence.  What is `k`?  What is `a[0]` (the first element in the stream)?  What is `a[1]`?

Comment: @toddsundsted Suppose I know the first `k` elements of the sequence: a[0], a[1], ..., a[1]. Now I want to calculate `a[n]` for `n` > `k` using function `f`.

Answer (score 3):

It will be possible to generalize it for any k, using an array for `a` and another `k` parameter, and having, f.i., the function with a `rest...` parameter.

```
def next(a1:Any, ..., ak:Any, f: (Any, ..., Any) => Any):Stream[Any] {
  val n = f(a1, ..., ak)
  Stream.cons(n, next(a2, ..., n, f))
}

val myStream = next(init1, ..., initk)
```

in order to have the 1000th do `next.drop(1000)`

An Update to show how this could be done with varargs. Beware that there is no arity check for the passed function:

```
object Test extends App {

def next(a:Seq[Long], f: (Long*) => Long): Stream[Long] = {
  val v = f(a: _*)
  Stream.cons(v, next(a.tail ++ Array(v), f))
}

def init(firsts:Seq[Long], rest:Seq[Long], f: (Long*) => Long):Stream[Long] = {
  rest match {
    case Nil => next(firsts, f)
    case x :: xs => Stream.cons(x,init(firsts, xs, f))
  }
}

def sum(a:Long*):Long = {
  a.sum
}

val myStream = init(Seq[Long](1,1,1), Seq[Long](1,1,1), sum)


myStream.take(12).foreach(println)
```

}

Comment: How do you get the initial `k`elements ?

Comment: It's not part of the question, I've assumed that they are known. As it is for Fibonacci, you set the first two as being 0 and 1.

Comment: @andypetrella yes, you are right, I assume the first `k` elements are known.

Comment: I meant how does your function answer the question of returning `a[i]`, for `1 ≤ i ≤ k`. We all agreee that those `k` initial elements are assumed to be known, but I wanted to point out that from what I understand, your `myStream` starts at `a[k+1]` and that dropping the first 1000 won't give you `a[1000]`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't took that. You're right for the first. What could be done is to Stream the first k a, then delegate to the next function. I'm gonna update it with the related solution including varargs... but no check on arity :/

Answer (score 3):

Is this OK?
(a[i] = f(a[i-k], a[i-k+1], ... a[i-1]) instead of a[i] = f(a[i-1], a[i-2], ... a[i-k]), since I prefer to this way)

```
/**
  Generating a Stream[T] by the given first k items and a function map k items to the next one.
*/
def getStream[T](f : T => Any,a : T*): Stream[T] = { 
  def invoke[T](fun: T => Any, es: T*): T = {
    if(es.size == 1) fun.asInstanceOf[T=>T].apply(es.head)
    else invoke(fun(es.head).asInstanceOf[T => Any],es.tail :_*)
  }
  Stream.iterate(a){ es => es.tail :+ invoke(f,es: _*)}.map{ _.head }
}
```

For example, the following code to generate Fibonacci sequence.

```
scala> val fn = (x: Int, y: Int) => x+y
fn: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>

scala> val fib = getStream(fn.curried,1,1)
fib: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> fib.take(10).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55)
```

The following code can generate a sequence {an} where a1 = 1, a2 = 2, a3 = 3, a(n+3） = a(n) + 2a(n+1) + 3a(n+2).

```
scala> val gn = (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) => x + 2*y + 3*z
gn: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>

scala> val seq = getStream(gn.curried,1,2,3)
seq: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> seq.take(10).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 14, 50, 181, 657, 2383, 8644, 31355)
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer, that you are probably looking for, is a pattern to define your `Stream` once you have fixed a chosen `k` for the arity of `f` (i.e. you have a fixed type for f). The following pattern gives you a `Stream` which `n`-th element is the term `a[n]` of your sequence:

```
def recStreamK [A](f : A ⇒ A ⇒ ... A) (x1:A) ... (xk:A):Stream[A] =
  x1 #:: recStreamK (f) (x2)(x3) ... (xk) (f(x1)(x2) ... (xk))
```

(credit : it is very close to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8644323/47978) of andy petrella, except that the initial elements are set up correctly, and consequently the rank in the Stream matches that in the sequence)

**If you want to generalize over `k`, this is possible** in a type-safe manner (with arity checking) in Scala, using prioritized overlapping implicits. The code (˜80 lines) is available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/1548553). I'm afraid I got a little carried away, and explained it as an detailed & overlong blog post [there](http://blog.garillot.net/post/15147165154/every-single-freshman-cs-question-in-80-lines-of-scala).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we cannot generalize over number and be type safe at the same time. So we’ll have to do it all manually:

```
def seq2[T, U](initials: Tuple2[T, T]) = new {
  def apply(fun: Function2[T, T, T]): Stream[T] = {
    initials._1 #::
    initials._2 #::
    (apply(fun) zip apply(fun).tail).map {
      case (a, b) => fun(a, b)
    }
  }
}
```

And we get `def fibonacci = seq2((1, 1))(_ + _)`.

```
def seq3[T, U](initials: Tuple3[T, T, T]) = new {
  def apply(fun: Function3[T, T, T, T]): Stream[T] = {
    initials._1 #::
    initials._2 #::
    initials._3 #::
    (apply(fun) zip apply(fun).tail zip apply(fun).tail.tail).map {
      case ((a, b), c) => fun(a, b, c)
    }
  }
}

def tribonacci = seq3((1, 1, 1))(_ + _ + _)
```

… and up to 22.

I hope the pattern is getting clear somehow. (We could of course improve and exchange the `initials` tuple with separate arguments. This saves us a pair of parentheses later when we use it.) If some day in the future, the Scala macro language arrives, this hopefully will be easier to define.

Comment: Hmm, the `def`s should be `lazy val`s rather.